# Is it possible to have a better performance with C4.5 than Bagged tree?

Tags: machine-learning, decision-trees, accuracy

I am not sure but I have read that Bagged tree is used to improve the accuracy of a signle tree methods such as C4.5 but applying both of them over the same dataset I got better accuracy with C4.5, 100% while the Bagged tree gave me 97%
Is this result acceptable or not?

Comment: How are you getting the 100% and 97%? Is it from testing on the training data?

Comment: It is for testing

Comment: Some more details might be helpful.  100% accuracy indicates either a really easy problem, or data leakage (/flawed train-test split), or a small test set.

Comment: Yes it was a small test data with 400 rows

Comment: I'm still skeptical of 100% accuracy on a test set; 400 is small, but not so small that I'd chalk it up entirely to luck...